# Shipping quote at checkout

Tags: magento-1, shipping, delivery

A UK-based shop I look after ships products worldwide. For anything under 2kg they use Royal Mail which have prices by weight across 4 shipping zones, so I have just used a simple lookup table.

For anything over 2kg, the shop would send via courier, and although couriers charge by weight, the final cost could be vastly different depending on which country they are shipping to.

It seems that couriers do not price by shipping zone, but instead price by weight and the specific country. What is the best way of getting the shipping price accurate?

Is there such a thing as an extension which will take the weight and shipping address, send the details to a shipping company, and return a shipping cost to charge to the customer?

If this is not possible, how are other people tackling this issue so that they do not under-charge for international shipping?

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can recollect the shipping rates using:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

They only extension that I know of that can do this perfectly is [Webshop Apps premium matrix rate](http://www.webshopapps.com/eu/premium-matrixrate-shipping-extension.html). I've used it for rules like yours before and it can be quite advanced with algorithms etc etc. Also they have an extensive Wiki page with explanation on how to use it and example CSV on how to set up the rule.

There is one minor detail, editing the rules is a pain. You either have to do it directly in the database or have the original CSV stored somewhere and edit and reupload that one.

I'm normally not in the habit of suggesting just one extension but in this case it's the only one I want to recommend.

Comment: Is possible can i enter weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate, because Default UPS, FEDEX, DHL required products weight as KG, but i am using Grams for webshopapps metrix rate. Is possible can i use products weight as KG in webshopapps metrix rate.

Comment: In webshopapps metrix rate, we need to enter weight as grams, i need th products weight as KG for default FEDEX,DHL,UPS, how can i enter products weight as KG in webshopapps matrix rate,

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the default use case for table rates.

You add **weight**, **country** and maybe **state** to a csv and the **price for shipping**, and then magento filters the correct result

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle this properly, you will need to implement a custom module.

We faced a similar issue where we used table rates, however as you pointed out these are only accurate to a certain point.

To overcome this, we created a custom module to query our shipping partner (in our case via XML integration) that took into account the total weight of all items in the cart on the **Cart** page and **Checkout Page**.

The shipping quotes are accurate and there are no longer any surprises.

A fully customized shipping module might not be as expensive as you would think, you can create a Project for free on many freelancer sites with absolutely no commitment, select the candidates that meet your criteria.

I would consult your shipping partner to see if you are able to integrate with them, if this is not possible, I would look around and consult with other shipping agencies.

Good luck!